# What is the most preferred approach of LAN gaming in Counter Strike 1.6 or Condition Zero?

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

The issue is common for both CS1.6 and C-Zero. I am trying to connect with 3 other laptops in an ad-hoc network for LAN gaming. Three Dell Laptops and one Acer. All have different OS viz. Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit in two laptops and mine and the other laptop has Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit. Somehow we successfully connect and start playing. But all of a sudden, there is a sudden surge in the latency and the game lags and freezes almost frequently and it is impossible to play. All the players are affected due to this. In the game, when I create a server it is never visible to any other users.

**CS servers made in Home Premium OS are not visible on LAN ?**

We tried to reduce the latency. I am not some professional at this game actually we all are just having moderate expertise or maybe little expertise. In the console I tried to make the following changes before starting the gameplay:

```
rate 25000
cl_cmdrate 80
cl_updaterate 80
```

But this made no difference. As I mentioned earlier we connect to an ad-hoc network created by one user and all others connect to server created in the game by any user. The ad-hoc network works for some and doesn't work for others. My laptop cannot get the server made by my friend in ad-hoc. The above approach didn't work sometimes. So we tried the `connect <IP Address>` approach which works for all but the above described lag problem persists.

I am not so well-versed with networking so I may have misspelled, misused or maybe unaware of some jargon's pertaining to it. So my question is what approach should be followed so the game works without any issues on all systems in LAN gaming ?

Comment: Could be a large number of things:  Poor server (overheating, underpowered, etc) or other issues with server; conflicts due to using wireless or a hub rather than a wired switch/router, or crappy switch/hub; poor wiring; connecting using external IP rather than internal; bad network drivers... Try to narrow it down to one of those.  Also, if you're seeing lag on the lan you want to LOWER than cmdrate and updaterate, not increase them.  Try setting `sv_maxupdaterate` and `sv_maxcmdrate` to around 20 or 30 on the server.

Comment: I've never tried to run this over wireless, but considering the game was made in the late 90's I can't imagine it has very good support for it... By far the easiest way to set this up is with a switch and 4 ethernet connections. Something like this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122005

Answer (score 1):

Wireless is a very poor choice for LAN gaming - only one client can be submitting something at a time, and when there's a conflict, both senders wait a random amount of time before sending again.  Even with just two clients, this can kill your ping.

What you want is a [switch](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=-1&isNodeId=1&Description=gigabit+switch&x=0&y=0) or a [router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=-1&isNodeId=1&Description=gigabit+router&x=0&y=0), then hook up all your laptops to it using [ethernet wires](http://www.monoprice.com/products/search.asp?spcDB=10232&spcWord=Cat+6+Network+Cables&keyword=cat6).  Do **not** use a hub in place of a switch/router, as this will have the same issues as wireless.

Routers and ethernet cords are so commonplace these days that most likely, between the four of you, you can scrap some together without having to buy anything.  If this does not fix your issue, let us know.

Comment: We have [this](http://www.shopping.com/TP-Link-TP-LINK-TL-WR740N-150Mbps-Wireless-Lite-N-Router-IEEE-802-11n-IEEE-802-11g-IEEE-802-11b-Built-in-4-p/info?sb=1) router already. Can we use it to do LAN gaming in Wireless without the above issues prevailing?

Comment: @SilentAssassin: You should find a router that has wired ports, and connect to it via wires.  The issue is not the Ad-Hoc network, it's the wireless protocol itself.